# Python 3.5 on Windows - Overwriting files created by other users "PermissionError: [Errno 13]"

Tags: windows, python-3.x, file-permissions, windows-server-2008-r2, overwrite

I'm writing a python script to take one file, alter it produce multiple new files based on the first. The idea is that if the first is updated, me or my other colleagues can run the script on our server (running Windows Server 2008 r2) and propagate the changes to the other files.

However we've hit a snag when it comes to, what i assume boils down to, windows file permissions.

When the script creates the files it creates them with permissions as follows:

- User that ran the script: Full Control, Read, Read & Execute, Modify, Write
- Administrators Group: Full Control, Read, Read & Execute, Modify, Write
- SYSTEM: Full Control, Read, Read & Execute, Modify, Write
- Users Group: Read, Read & Execute

I've observed the following behaviors:

- When me or my boss run the script, and none of the child files exist, the script runs fine and creates new ones.
- When me or my boss run the script, the child files exist and were created by a previous run by the same person running the script, the script runs fine and overwrites the existing files.
- When I run the script, the child files exist but were created by my boss running the script, the script fails with `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied.
- When my boss runs the script, the child files exist but were created by me running the script, the script fails with `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied.

Both me and my boss are Administrators according to the User list in Control Panel so according to the permissions should have no issues, but we still get the error.

What am i doing wrong?

Is there a way to alter file permissions from the script, or delete the files before the script writes?

Code follows:

```
#All variables are set above
#They have no bearing on file permissions other than setting the paths to read/write
fileIn = io.open(filePath, mode='r')
print ("Reading " + filePath)
for line in fileIn:
    for x in range(0,5):
        contentsOut[x] += line
        if line[:len(seekLine)] == seekLine:
            contentsOut[x] += catSection.format(catStrings[x])
            print ("written category string")
fileIn.close()
for x in range(0,5):
    fileOutName = basePath + fileFormat.format(catStrings[x])
    fileOut = io.open(fileOutName, mode='wt', encoding='utf_8',newline='\r\n')
    print ("Writing " + fileOutName)
    fileOut.write(contentsOut[x])
    fileOut.close()
    print ("Write finished")
```

EDIT:
I have since changed the algorithm to remove the file before writing and it's giving even more bizarre results.

For some reason if the files that exist were created by me, my boss cannot delete them by running the script and is given `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied` when he hits the `os.remove(fileOutName)` line.

I however have no issues, and can run the script fine no matter if it was me or my boss who created the files.

I really need to know why this is happening before I look into a solution.
I've also since been told that only admins should be allowed to do this, so the current file permissions look fine assuming they're not getting in the way.

```
fileIn = io.open(filePath, mode='r')
print ("Reading " + filePath)
for line in fileIn:
    for x in range(0,noOfOutFiles):
        contentsOut[x] += line
        if line[:len(seekLine)] == seekLine:
            contentsOut[x] += catSection.format(catStrings[x])
            print ("written category string")
fileIn.close()
for x in range(0,noOfOutFiles):
    fileOutName = basePath + '\\' + scopePath + '\\' + typePath + '\\' + fileFormat.format(catStrings[x])
    if os.path.exists(fileOutName):
        print ("Deleting " + fileOutName)
        os.remove(fileOutName)
    print ("Writing " + fileOutName)
    fileOut = io.open(fileOutName, mode='wt', encoding='utf_8',newline='\r\n')
    fileOut.write(contentsOut[x])
    fileOut.close()
    print ("Write finished")
```

EDIT: I ran icacls on '.' (current directory) and one of the produced files, here is the result:

Current Directory:

```
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
BUILTIN\Users:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
BUILTIN\Users:(I)(CI)(AD)
BUILTIN\Users:(I)(CI)(WD)
SERVERNAME\Me:(I)(F)
CREATOR OWNER:(I)(OI)(CI)(IO)(F)
```

File:

```
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)
SERVERNAME\Me:(I)(F)
```

My boss isn't specifically listed but I am, which is odd, neither of us remember adding that permission.

Comment: If UAC is enabled, then your administrator token is split in two, one token that's restricted and another that's unrestricted. The unrestricted token is also called the 'elevated' token, since it has a "High" mandatory integrity level. Check `whoami /groups /fo list`. If the command prompt wasn't "run as administrator", then you should see that BUILTIN\Administrators is set as "Group used for deny only". This means ACEs in an security descriptor DACL that grant access to administrators aren't applicable to your non-elevated token.

Comment: Note that directories can grant the `FILE_DELETE_CHILD` [File Access Right](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg258116), which implicitly allows a user that has this right to delete files and subdirectories. It appears you have this right for the directory in question, but your boss does not. Check `icacls dirpath` to list the ACEs in the directory's DACL.

Comment: @eryksun the thing is that my boss can delete tehm manually, by going into explorer and hitting delete. It's just the script that can't delete them when he's running it.

Comment: @eryksun added the results of icacls and it's odd

Comment: Did you create the directory? `dir /q` shows the owner. There's an inherited ACE for `CREATOR OWNER` that grants full control to the creator of files (object inherit) and directories (container inherit). Since you have full control of the directory, you can delete files that your boss created. As to Explorer, it elevates an administrator to delete a file, but there should be a prompt asking for administrator permission.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the win32security model, you will have full control of setting file permissions for the different groups.

http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/add-security-to-a-file.html

```
dacl = win32security.ACL ()
dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce (win32security.ACL_REVISION, con.FILE_GENERIC_READ, everyone)
dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce (win32security.ACL_REVISION, con.FILE_GENERIC_READ | con.FILE_GENERIC_WRITE, user)
dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce (win32security.ACL_REVISION, con.FILE_ALL_ACCESS, admins)
```

Comment: But do you know why this might be happening anyway? as regardless of permissions this behavior seems odd.

Comment: What's the permissions of the folder in which the file is being created? as far as I know, in Windows, it inherits the permissions of the parent folder. You might want to check that.